# Avoid lineplot to draw line for non-contiguous x-values

Tags: python, plot

I have this dataframe where row names correspond to a date (Dias) and columns are some variable statistics: min, max and mean (Dato). The code I am using to plot these statistics is

```
plt.figure(figsize = [8, 8])
ax = sns.lineplot(data = pd.melt(x_days[['Dato','Min', 'Max', 'Dias']], ['Dias']), 
                  x = "Dias", y = "value", hue = "variable", marker = "o",
                  palette=['blue', 'gold', 'limegreen'])
```

and the graph I get is the next one

[image]

I want the plot NOT to show the line between 06-04 and 06-22 since y-values for these points are
`nan`in my dataframe. How could I do that? Thanks for your help.